# NDepend not seeing assembly attributes in Portable Class Libraries

Tags: .net, portable-class-library, ndepend

I have a solution that uses a few portable class libraries and I can't figure out how to fix the default rules that look for certain attributes to be defined on the assembly when the assembly is a portable class library.

For example, the rule `Mark assemblies with CLSCompliant`

```
warnif count > 0 from a in Application.Assemblies where 
  !a.HasAttribute("System.CLSCompliantAttribute".AllowNoMatch())
select a
```

Based on the output it appears that NDepend is looking for the attribute as defined in mscorlib but in a portable class library the attribute is defined in System.Runtime.dll.

Is there a way to change the rule so it handles PCL projects properly?

*Note: NDepend version 5.2.1.8320*

Comment: Bryan please send us a quick repro at *support at ndepend dot com* (VS solution + project) and we'll see if it is a bug or if this can be fixed by tuning something. Thanks

Comment: @PatrickfromNDependteam I just sent the email with a simple example attached.

Comment: This was a bug in NDepend that was not analyzing well WinRT third-party assemblies. We juste released v5.4.0 and it is now fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has indeed been fixed as of NDepend v5.4.0.